# Setting up a transparent proxy server a la unblock-us.com

Tags: windows, transparent-proxy

I have a Windows Server set up in America (I'm from the UK), and am thinking of setting it up so I can mask my IP like http://www.unblock-us.com. Basically what it does is make it look like my IP is in North America when really it's in the UK.

Is it a transparent proxy I would need to do this? Am I able to do this with just the server?

I have only just started looking at this, so just really looking to see if it's possible first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't need a transparent proxy(which is something you'd run between your network and the internet, well, transparently), you'd need a proxy (which is a system sitting somewhere passing through traffic - some configuration needed). You'd need a server in the country in question (vps do fine), and a proxy software - [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) is simple enough for this, since we're not talking caching.

If you wanted to run a transparent proxy I THINK you could run tinyproxy at the router, and point it at a second proxy through the upstream proxy directive in the config file, but I've not tried it yet.